# How to generate the web.xml Deployment Descriptor Stub in an existing Eclipse project?

Tags: eclipse, web.xml

How can I generate the web.xml in an existing Eclipse project ? I am aware of generating it while creating the project, but not when the project has already been created.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To generate the web.xml file, known as the Deployment Descriptor Stub, on a project let's say "MyProject"

open the contents of your project folder,

[image: Project Folder Contents]

right click on "Deployment Descriptor: MyProject" and select "Generate Depoyment Descriptor Stub".

[image: Deployment Descriptor Context Menu]

After that, you will see that web.xml has been created under the folder 
WebContent->WEB-INF.

Answer (score 2):

Right Click on project name on "Package Explorer" tab, hover over "Java EE tools" and click on "Generate Deployment Descriptor Stub".